# scroll bar appears at top nav bar while using jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

I am using bootstrap nav bar along with jquery and angular js.

When I click the nav bar button, scroll bar appears at top for one second and it disappears again 
[image: Please refer the below image]

You can check this link for reference https://kartheek-sarabu.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Scroll bar appear on nav div becouse it contains floating "Contact Me" element with "margin-right: -15px;". Remove it and scrollbar dissapears.

To restore "Contact Me" position in right, change padding-right from 15px to 0px  on .container-fluid:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

This will fix your issue. But why scrollbar appears only then you call "animate()" on body, it out of my answer scope.